# Root access in Tor 6,0.5?

Tags: security, debian

25/9/2016
Bonjour tout le monde,

While launching Tor 6,05 as standard user, I check the connexions and noticed these lines :

tcp        0      0 localhost:58186         localhost:ipp           ESTABLISHED root       13693       -
tcp        0      0 localhost:42429         localhost:9150          TIME_WAIT   root       0           -
tcp        0      0 192.168.0.15:37517      46.19.93.214:https      ESTABLISHED administrateur 24447       -
tcp        0      0 localhost:37651         localhost:9151          ESTABLISHED administrateur 26433       2111/firefox
tcp        0      0 localhost:42432         localhost:9150          TIME_WAIT   root       0           -
tcp        0      0 localhost:9151          localhost:37651         ESTABLISHED administrateur 26434       -
tcp        0      0 localhost:ipp           localhost:58186         ESTABLISHED root       14340       -
tcp        0      0 localhost:37650         localhost:9151          ESTABLISHED administrateur 26400       2111/firefox
tcp        0      0 localhost:9151          localhost:37650         ESTABLISHED administrateur 24442       -
tcp        0      0 192.168.0.15:35375      tor.epow0.org:9001      ESTABLISHED administrateur 24509       -
tcp        0      0 localhost:37655         localhost:9151          ESTABLISHED administrateur 26682       2111/firefox
tcp        0      0 localhost:42431         localhost:9150          TIME_WAIT   root       0           -
tcp        0      0 localhost:9151          localhost:37655         ESTABLISHED administrateur 26683

See those lines as root user ?

Questions :

Port 9150 is linked with Tor, right ?

I know "time wait" means no more active connexions,
I know these connexions are localhost,
but ...

How Tor managed to get root access ? I never used it as root and installed it as standard user.

I am worrying about privilege escalation.

Cordialement.

Comment: This doesn't appear to show tor with root access, this appears to show the root user using tor. The left hand side shows the source, the right the destination. The destination is tor, not the source.

Answer (score 1):

Port 9150 is a Tor SOCKS port by default, so something was using *your local* SOCKS[port 9150] and *your local* ControlPort to control Tor via telnet protocol, default port is 9151. The Tor itself seems to behave fine, no rooting/jailbreaking so far. Please post your `torrc` config if you need to take a deeper look, but your log looks OK and very common for TorButton or something similar like Tor Browser Bundle.